# How can I mock SOAPConnection and SOAPConnectionFactory

Tags: java, soap, junit, easymock

Here is my code:

```java
URL url = new URL(getURL());  
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnFactory.createConnection();`
response=soapConnection.call(soapMsg, url);
```

I'm trying to create a mock for `SOAPConnection` but I get an exception.
Can anyone suggest me any work-around for this?

My test is something like this:
I created a `SOAPMessage` object and `URL` object.

```java
Resource classUnderTest = new Resource(); 
SOAPConnection mockConnection = EasyMock.createMock(SOAPConnection.class); 
EasyMock.expect(mockConnection.call(soapmsg, url)).andReturn(soapMsg); 
EasyMock.replay(mockConnection); 
WhiteBox.setinternalState(classUnderTest, SOAPConnection.class, mockConnection);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to mock the entire service on a localhost port. I've written a [small library](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf) which does most of the heavily lifting.